# How to find a date range for a stock price? Datetime not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-datareader

Okay so i am trying to get a price range for a stock.

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from datetime import time

start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016,12,28)
SPWR = pdr.get_data_yahoo('SPWR' start, end)
```

I am running Python 3.6

Comment: have you considered using `pandas`? It has lots of tools for working with timeseries.

Comment: It looks like you're using `pandas-datareader` (`pdr`).  Best to include that in your import statements.

Comment: You're missing a comma: `get_data_yahoo('SPWR', start, end)`

Comment: What is the expected and the actual result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported `datetime as dt`, but you're trying to refer to `datetime` in your code.  Swap out `datetime` for `dt` and you should be good syntactically.

Note, however, that Yahoo recently changed its API endpoints.  That means `get_data_yahoo()` now returns an error.  This is a [a known issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/315), currently unresolved.

Comment: Hey thatnk you guys.  I actually switched it to google and it pulled the data.  Thank you so much.  As a newb I have been trying to figure this out for 2 days.  It was getting frustrating.

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer cleared up your original question about `Datetime not defined`, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  I can definitely appreciate getting stuck on frustrating code!